# swift if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have an if statement in swift that I can not figure out how to set up. I want to check two variables and check if they do not equal a certain value. Then the variable that does not equal the certain value should be set to a new variable. I am comparing two variables. For example, if x != y then x should be given a new value or if z != y then z should also be given a new value.

Here is my code:

```
if (message.ReceiverId != self.loggedInUserUid  || message.senderId != self.loggedInUserUid) {

//Print the variable that is not equal to the loggedInUserUid
//and set it to a variable.

}
```

Comment: What's the problem with that code? What's the current result and the expected result? You didn't describe the problem very well.

Comment: Seems like you just need two `if` statements - one for each check.

Comment: @CharlieFish What I am trying to accomplish is to check if message.ReceiverId or message.senderId is not equal to self.loggedInUserUid and what ever variable is not equal to self.loggedInUserUid should be set to a new variable

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your clarifications. What do you want to do if both values don't match `self.loggedInUserUid`? What if both match?

Comment: The way I set it up both are never going to match. only one will match and the one that does not match needs to be set to a new variable @rmaddy

Comment: @juelizabeth You want to set both to `loggedInUserUid` if they not equals?

Comment: Please do not edit your question to state it has been answered. People know it has been answered because you have accepted an answer.

Comment: Your latest change to your question completely negates the whole point of the question.

Comment: well I keep losing reputations all because I didn't know how to word/ask a question, which was solved. I assumed that is what this site was about, helping people. @rmaddy

Comment: Your question was down voted because it wasn't clear. If you edit your question, only do so to make it clearer. Do not edit it to reflect the chosen answer. Doing so negates the point of posting the question. To clarify your question you should summarize the responses made in your comments. Don't edit the code, just add clarifying information about what input you can have and what the results should be in each case. That is what is missing in your current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
if message.ReceiverId != self.loggedInUserUid {
    var newVariable = message.ReceiverId
} else if message.senderId != self.loggedInUserUid {
    var newVariable = message.senderId
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to have an "or" statement? Could it not be enough with an "else if"?

```
if message.ReceiverId != self.loggedInUserUid {
// Code to be executed...
} else if message.senderId != self.loggedInUserUid {
// Other code to be executed...
}
```